# Media Queries not acknowledged in some cellphones

Tags: android, css

I am working with media queries and my problem is with cellphones primarily android cellphones.
The url is: http://home.comcast.net/~shadowpeopleorg/mobilestorytest.html

When working correctly, the web page’s banner should be at the top, centered with gold letters on a black background and the background should be a parchment beige color.

The queries work perfectly with ipod touch in both ‘portrait’ and ‘landscape’ views but does not work on safari browser cellphones in 'portrait' rotation.

The query style sheets are not acknowledged in android based cellphones in either portrait or landscape.  I cannot determine what the problem is but I assume it has something to do with the meta viewpoint declaration in the header.

I would really appreciate those with cellphones to check the test page and report back whether the style sheet attributes are showing up in both portrait and landscape views.

I’ve tried:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
<link rel="stylesheet" media="only screen and (max-width: 480px)" type = "text/css"href="mobilestory.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" media="only screen and (min-width: 481px)" type = "text/css" href="aaastory.css" />
```

Also:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" media="only screen and (max-width: 480px) and (orientation : landscape)" type = "text/css"href="mobilestory.css" />
```

And:

```
link rel="stylesheet" media="only screen and (max-width: 480px) and (orientation : portrait)" type = "text/css"href="mobilestory.css" />
```

I’ve also changed the meta tag to:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1">
```

Comment: I don't know why this won't post but I also changed the meta tag to : <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1">

Answer (score 0):

The point here is your css is totally distorted for

```
@media screen an

d (min-width: 481px)
h1 {
border: none;
margin-right: 120px;
font-family: Times New Roman;
line-height: normal;
color: grey;
text-align: right;
text-decoration: none;
font-size: 100%;
font-weight: normal;
```

Instead of `margin-right: 120px;` do `text-align: center;` and use percentages for margins and all ... Try some responsive designing. It will work for all phones or tablets or pc.

And the golden color is not coming neither in chrome nor in android tab. Please help me through this if there is an issue.

[image: Header moving right]

Please look at the image this is reproduceable in samsung note 2 landscape mode ? I hope this is the part you wanna get fixed?

Comment: Concerning the margin right comment and the suggestion to use responsive designing...You were looking at the WRONG style sheet attached to the page.

Comment: @ Anobik   Concerning the margin right comment and the suggestion to use responsive designing...You were looking at the WRONG style sheet attached to the page.  The correct style sheet is the mobilestory.css and the h1 is text aligned.

Comment: Wait let me take a look.

Comment: Please see the image some thing from my desktop and even in samsung note 8 landscape mode. Please let me know you wanna fix this design only ?

Comment: There are two style sheets, one for desktop and one for mobile. They are two completely different style sheets. The desktop css is fine and does not have the gold and black banner.  The samsung version doesn't even pick up on the media query at all and simply shows the desktop css.  Media queries are becoming a far more complex issue than I thought it would be.  Andriods simply pick up the mobilestory.css reference but shows everything in stripped down black and white.

Comment: The image I shared happens in landscape mode of samsung note 8. If you can please look at the mobile style sheet with h1  tag css. Doesnt seem that big an issue Please try and let me know :)